# What's the use of 'get controller/action' in routes.rb in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

When generating a controller, rails automatically put 'get controller/action' at top of routes.rb file for each of the resourceful action (such as index, new, create, edit. etc.). What's purpose of this 'get'? Since there is a 'resources' for the same model in routes.rb, can we get rid of this 'get'? Is the 'get' needed for 'put' custom action in routes.rb?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove that route.

The proper layout for basic resource routing in Rails 3.1 follows this format:

```
resources :users do # Provides GET /users, /users/new, /users/:id, /users/:id/edit, POST /users, PUT /users/:id, DELETE /users/:id
  # Additional routes which return collections (not CRUD)
  collection do
    get :search # /users/search
  end

  # Additional routes which return single models (not CRUD)
  member do
    put :add_friend # /users/:id/add_friend
  end
end
```

You can read the full Rails routing guide here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Did you mean 'get' can be removed for 7 default RESTful routes as well? It seems OK to delete it for resourceful custom routes.

Comment: The default RESTful routes are automatically handled by the `resources :users` line. You can see them here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions.